# one control with different background color in different styles in android

Tags: android, styles

I have 2 activity: Activity1 , Activity2

theme of Activity1 is blue and the other one is orange

now I have an xml layout (sort_items.xml) that inflated in these activities

I want to be this layout's background color blue when I open Activity1 and be orange when I open Activity2.

I created 2 style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppThemeOrange"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarOrange</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeBlue"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarBlue</item>
</style>
```

and these themes are attributed to their activitoes in manifest.xml

also two color in colors.xml

```
<color name="orange">#ffa726</color>
<color name="blue">#119eff</color>
```

and this is sort_items.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="???"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">

    ...

 </LinearLayout>
```

now how do I set the layout1 (in sort_items.xml) background color that change automatically in each activity?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but did you tried

```
mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
```

Comment: thanks but this code is useful when we know what activity is opened. but  this layout will inflated in other activities and we don't know what theme has that activity.